# Invalid requirement, parse error at "''"

Tags: python, multithreading, paramiko, invalid-argument

I'm trying to connect to host by different threads in python but getting error sometimes(1 times in 25 times execution)
I have seen similar threads and hoped to update pip to 8.1.1 will solve this but did not solve though.

code snippet:

```
def getkpis(self,cmd,host):
    ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        ssh.connect(host,username='root',look_for_keys=True)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        paramiko.util.log_to_file("kpiparamiko.log")
        output=stdout.read()
        appendarray=output.split('\n')
        sys.stdin.flush()
        ssh.close()
    except paramiko.SSHException, e:
        print str(e)
```

Error seen:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 811, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 764, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/conf/home/smodugu/kpiparse.py", line 56, in getkpis
ssh.connect(host,username='root',look_for_keys=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 338, in     connect
t.start_client()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 493, in       start_client
raise e
RequirementParseError: Invalid requirement, parse error at "''"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I was able to get around this by using an older version of setuptools, `pip install "setuptools<34"` but then today the problem came back. I was able to get around it by adding a 0.1 second sleep in the loop that was queuing the threads. Why multiple threaded calls to paramiko's SSHClient cause this error with pip/setuptools, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the connect function is not thread safe in the version of paramiko for python2.7

The solution is to use the `Lock` object from the threading module,
`from threading import Lock`.
Then wrap the call to the `connect` function of the paramiko client with the lock object.
For example:

`from threading import Lock
lock = Lock()
...
lock.acquire()
client.connect(...)
lock.release()`

The code above makes so that only one thread will use the connect at a time, which solves the problem that the function is not thread safe.

*** I am not sure if the problem exists in newer versions of paramiko, worth a look.